# chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab seems to double the image size

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I'm interested in capturing the active tab showing in the chrome browser with a chrome extension.

I'm currently using this function: [captureVisibleTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab)

Although the zoom level in my browser is 100%, I'm getting images back that are 2x as large as what I'd expect, regardless of the website and regardless of the image format.

Is there something I'm missing? I can't seem to find anything in the docs that is related to image scale.

Comment: If you draw the captured image on a canvas, what's the size of the canvas and how do you draw on it? Please provide more details/code